# How to get selenium to wait on multiple elements to load

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following code to wait on all 4 elements to be loaded before proceeding with the screen scrape; however, the code is not waiting on all 4 nor is throwing a timeout error -- it just proceeds and I get an error on elements that haven't yet been loaded.

What am I missing to get Selenium to wait until all four elements are present before proceeding?

````
        CSSSelector1_toWaitOn = "#div1 table tbody tr td"
        CSSSelector2_toWaitOn = "#div2 table tbody tr:nth-child(5) td"
        CSSSelector3_toWaitOn = "#div3 table tbody tr:nth-child(5) td"
        CSSSelector4_toWaitOn = "#div4 table tbody tr td"


        browser.get(url)
        browser_delay = 15  # seconds
        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, browser_delay).until(expected_conditions and (
                expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector1_toWaitOn)) and
                expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector2_toWaitOn)) and
                expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector3_toWaitOn)) and
                expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector4_toWaitOn))))
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Selenium timeout")```
````

Comment: What is the exact error message returned by Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to combine them all into a single wait, you can have a separate wait for each.

```
...

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, browser_delay)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector1_toWaitOn))
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector2_toWaitOn))
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector3_toWaitOn))
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector4_toWaitOn))))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Selenium timeout")
```

Just be aware, there are 3 levels of interaction within Selenium for elements:

1. present - the element is in the DOM. If you attempt to click on or get text from, etc. a present (but not visble) element, an `ElementNotInteractable` exception will be thrown.
2. visible - the element is in the DOM and visible (e.g. not invisible, display: none, etc.)
3. clickable - the element is visible and enabled. For *most* cases, this is just... is it visible? The special cases would be elements like an INPUT button that is marked as disabled. An element that is styled as disabled (greyed out) using CSS, is not considered disabled.

Comment: I think the only thing that will do is wait item by item.

Comment: @boludoz That's what I stated in my first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

`WebDriverWait.until` expects callable object. This is an actual snippet from its source:

```
while True:
    try:
        value = method(self._driver)
        if value:
            return value
```

All `expected_contidition`s are callable objects. So in this case you need to compose them, something like following should work.

```
class composed_expected_conditions:
    def __init__(self, expected_conditions):
        self.expected_conditions = expected_conditions

    def __call__(self, driver):
        for expected_condition in self.expected_conditions:
            if not expected_condition(driver):
                return False

            return True
```

And pass it to the `until`

```
conditions = [
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector1_toWaitOn)), 
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector2_toWaitOn)),
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector3_toWaitOn)),
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector4_toWaitOn)),
]

WebDriverWait(browser, browser_delay).until(composed_expected_conditions(conditions))
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `presence_of_element_located(locator)` only checks that the element is present in the DOM. It does not mean that the element can be interacted with. Furthermore, the search process finds all the elements for given `locator` and returns first one.

Please check that the element is valid, available, and specific. In case there are multiple elements in the list, make sure your locator is specific enough to find the single element.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, we have a built-in solution for it.

```
conditions = [
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector1_toWaitOn)), 
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector2_toWaitOn)),
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector3_toWaitOn)),
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSSSelector4_toWaitOn)),
]
WebDriverWait(browser, browser_delay).until(expected_conditions.all_of(*conditions))
```

all_of() expects that all of the multiple "expected_conditions" are true.